# Add a "default sorting" menu to child store pages

Tags: plugins, sort, dropdown, customization

I'm new to WordPress WooCommerce and I can't figure out how to add a "default sorting" drop-down filter to my *category* shop pages. I know it's on the plain old "SHOP" page, but my navigation doesn't even show that page (I set that up that way by choice). I have category pages (Cupcakes, Balloons, Plush, Cakes) and sub-category pages (for example: Cupcakes—Flavors Cupcakes—Assortments, Cupcakes—Holiday&Seasonal [etc.]), and I would like to have a "sort-by (price, popularity, average rating, newest) drop-down menu on ALL of those unique pages.

Seems like such a basic thing. Does anyone know how to do this? Is it even possible?

I am using the "Shoppest" theme.

Here is my full archive-product.php page code.

```
<?php

/**

 * The Template for displaying product archives, including the main shop page 
which is a post type archive.

 *

 * Override this template by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/archive-
product.php
 *
 * @author      WooThemes
 * @package     WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version     2.0.0
 */


if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly


get_header('shop'); ?>


    <?php

        /**
     * Shoppest - remove woocommerce_output_content_wrapper & breadcrumb
     * 
     * woocommerce_before_main_content hook
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_output_content_wrapper - 10 (outputs opening divs for the content)
     * @hooked woocommerce_breadcrumb - 20
     */
    do_action('woocommerce_before_main_content');
?>

<?php
    // check sidebar position
    $options = get_option('shoppest');
    $layout = ( isset($options['shop_layout']) && !empty($options['shop_layout']) ) ? $options['shop_layout'] : 'sidebarleft';
    //echo $option['shop_layout'];
    if ( $layout != 'fullwidth' ) {
        $cssclass = 'span9';
        if ( $layout == 'sidebarleft') $cssclass .= ' contentright';
    } else {
        $cssclass = 'span12';
    }
?>

<div role="main" id="content" class="<?php echo $cssclass; ?>">

    <?php // make show page title false ?>

    <?php if ( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_show_page_title', false ) ) : ?>

        <h1 class="page-title"><?php woocommerce_page_title(); ?></h1>

    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php 
        /*
         *  Shoppest - remove woocommerce_archive_description [ that display description]
         *
         *  @hooked sama_shop_slider - 10
         */
        do_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description' );
    ?>

    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

        <?php
            $options = get_option('shoppest');
            $icon_layout = ( isset($options['shop_icon_layout']) ) ? $options['shop_icon_layout'] : true;
        ?>

            <div class="productFilter clearfix">

                <?php
                    /**
                     * Shoppest - remove woocommerce_result_count
                     *
                     * woocommerce_before_shop_loop hook
                     *
                     * @hooked woocommerce_result_count - 20
                     * @hooked woocommerce_catalog_ordering - 30
                     */
                    do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop' );
                ?>

                <?php if ($icon_layout) { ?>
                    <div class="displaytBy inline pull-right">
                        <?php _e( 'Display', 'samathemes' ); ?>
                        <div class="btn-group">
                            <button id="grid" class="btn btn-primary active"><i class="icon-th"></i></button>
                            <button id="list" class="btn"><i class="icon-list"></i></button>
                        </div>
                    </div><!--end displaytBy-->
                <?php } ?>

            </div><!--end productFilter-->
        <?php woocommerce_product_loop_start(); ?>

            <?php woocommerce_product_subcategories(); ?>

            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                <?php woocommerce_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); ?>

            <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

        <?php woocommerce_product_loop_end(); ?>

        <?php
            /**
             * woocommerce_after_shop_loop hook
             *
             * @hooked woocommerce_pagination - 10
             */
            do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop' );
        ?>

    <?php elseif ( ! woocommerce_product_subcategories( array( 'before' => woocommerce_product_loop_start( false ), 'after' => woocommerce_product_loop_end( false ) ) ) ) : ?>

        <?php woocommerce_get_template( 'loop/no-products-found.php' ); ?>

    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php
        /**
         * woocommerce_after_main_content hook
         *
         * @hooked woocommerce_output_content_wrapper_end - 10 (outputs closing divs for the content)
         */
        do_action('woocommerce_after_main_content');
    ?>

</div> <!-- end span9 -->

<?php
    /**
     * woocommerce_sidebar hook
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_get_sidebar - 10
     */
    if ( $layout != 'fullwidth' ) {
        do_action('woocommerce_sidebar');
    }
?>

<?php get_footer('shop'); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at whether or not your theme has an `archive-product.php` file in the woocommerce folder. This is a copy of the WooCommerce category template (which is displayed by `archive-product.php`.  As long as your template has the `do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop' );` action hook then the `woocommerce_catalog_ordering()` function should automatically be called with a priority of 30... as it says directly in the code comments. Either your theme templates need to be updated for WooCommerce 2.0 or your theme has intentionally removed the `woocommerce_catalog_ordering()` function from the `woocommerce_before_shop_loop`.

```
<?php
/**
 * The Template for displaying product archives, including the main shop page which is a post type archive.
 *
 * Override this template by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/archive-product.php
 *
 * @author      WooThemes
 * @package     WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version     2.0.0
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly

get_header('shop'); ?>

    <?php
        /**
         * woocommerce_before_main_content hook
         *
         * @hooked woocommerce_output_content_wrapper - 10 (outputs opening divs for the content)
         * @hooked woocommerce_breadcrumb - 20
         */
        do_action('woocommerce_before_main_content');
    ?>

        <?php if ( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_show_page_title', true ) ) : ?>

            <h1 class="page-title"><?php woocommerce_page_title(); ?></h1>

        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description' ); ?>

        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

            <?php
                /**
                 * woocommerce_before_shop_loop hook
                 *
                 * @hooked woocommerce_result_count - 20
                 * @hooked woocommerce_catalog_ordering - 30
                 */
                do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop' );
            ?>

            <?php woocommerce_product_loop_start(); ?>

                <?php woocommerce_product_subcategories(); ?>

                <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                    <?php woocommerce_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); ?>

                <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

            <?php woocommerce_product_loop_end(); ?>

            <?php
                /**
                 * woocommerce_after_shop_loop hook
                 *
                 * @hooked woocommerce_pagination - 10
                 */
                do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop' );
            ?>

        <?php elseif ( ! woocommerce_product_subcategories( array( 'before' => woocommerce_product_loop_start( false ), 'after' => woocommerce_product_loop_end( false ) ) ) ) : ?>

            <?php woocommerce_get_template( 'loop/no-products-found.php' ); ?>

        <?php endif; ?>

    <?php
        /**
         * woocommerce_after_main_content hook
         *
         * @hooked woocommerce_output_content_wrapper_end - 10 (outputs closing divs for the content)
         */
        do_action('woocommerce_after_main_content');
    ?>

    <?php
        /**
         * woocommerce_sidebar hook
         *
         * @hooked woocommerce_get_sidebar - 10
         */
        do_action('woocommerce_sidebar');
    ?>

<?php get_footer('shop'); ?>
```

**Updated based on your template code:**

Just because you are using WooCommerce 2.0 doesn't mean that your theme's templates were updated.  I have had to do that for several clients.  However, the action hook `do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop' );` *is* present.

I would:

1. verify whether it is in the markup (view source) and being hidden by CSS
2. check all the functions for something that would remove the function:  `remove_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'woocommerce_catalog_ordering', 30);`
3. check all the function for a modified definition of `woocommerce_catalog_ordering()`
4. rename the archive-product.php template to something else temporarily archive-productTEST.php so that WooCommerce will load it's default template instead

Without access to your site/code that is about all I can suggest.

Comment: Thank you for the response @helgatheviking! My archive product page definitely looks different than what you posted and I am running 2.0.0. I posted my full archive-product.php code within my original question. HAve you any idea what needs changing? Or perhaps I have set the store pages up incorrectly??? I don't think I have though since the browser reads "/shop/" before all of my added product category pages and single items. I am at a loss here!